# Ask 2 questions and have 3 different outcomes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to ask users with a MsgBox two seperate questions. Depending on what they select yes to print the appropriate set of drawings.

This is where I am at so far. The single option Yes & No will work but the Yes & Yes does not.

```
Dim acadMsgBox As String, exclMsgBox As String
Dim LoginName As String, destFolder As String

acadMsgBox = MsgBox("Print all AutoCad Drawings to PDF?", vbYesNo, "Drawings (" & Worksheets("Drawing Index").Range("D2") & " Package)")
exclMsgBox = MsgBox("Print all Excel Spreadsheets to PDF?", vbYesNo, "Spreadsheets (" & Worksheets("Drawing Index").Range("D2") & " Package)")

LoginName = UCase(GetUserID)
destFolder = "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Desktop\"

If acadMsgBox & exclMsgBox = vbYes Then
    Call AcadPlot
    On Error Resume Next
    Call ExcelPlot
    Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & destFolder, vbNormalFocus
ElseIf acadMsgBox = vbYes Then
    Call AcadPlot
    Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & destFolder, vbNormalFocus
ElseIf exclMsgBox = vbYes Then
    Call ExcelPlot
    Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & destFolder, vbNormalFocus
End If
```

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: `vbYes` is a constant with a value of 6.  `6 & 6` concatenates the strings "6" and "6", and gives you "66". You're probably looking for the `And` operator there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MsgBox` function returns a `VbMsgBoxResult` enum value, which is essentially a named `Long` constant.

> ```
> Dim acadMsgBox As String, exclMsgBox As String
> ```

Declare them `As VbMsgBoxResult`, not `As String`.

> ```
> If acadMsgBox & exclMsgBox = vbYes Then
> ```

Declaring them `As Long` would work too, but with `VbMsgBoxResult` you get free autocompletion after the `=` sign.

`&` is the *string concatenation operator*, [Comintern briefed you on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410962/ask-2-questions-and-have-3-different-outcomes#comment95632966_54410962). You want to use a *logical* operator here:

```
If acadMsgBox = vbYes And exclMsgBox = vbYes Then
```

Note  that this would involve a bitwise operation that wouldn't produce the expected outcome:

```
If acadMsgBox And exclMsgBox = vbYes Then
```